# writing or printing line by line to a text file from a get text field string

Tags: java, line, file-writing

I understand that my question might be repeated, but I couldn't find the answer I need in other question's answer,
I have a textArea where some data was appended there.
and I want to write that data into a file with the same style of lines as in the textArea
My textArea result looks like this

```
Type    Model   Serial      Country WTY START   WTY END     SER.STRT    SER.END     Int.Warrnty
1234    123    1234567      XXXXXX  2012-07-04  2015-07-03  2012-07-04  2015-07-03  Yes
5678    456    4567890      XXXXXX  2011-05-11  2014-06-24  ....-..-..  ....-..-..  No
```

When I try to write it to a text file it is written there like this after the yes, the second line is written immediately.

```
Type    Model   Serial      Country WTY START   WTY END     SER.STRT    SER.END     Int.Warrnty
1234    123    1234567      XXXXXX  2012-07-04  2015-07-03  2012-07-04  2015-07-03  Yes5678 456    4567890      XXXXXX  2011-05-11  2014-06-24  ....-..-..  ....-..-..  No
```

I tried to use print stream and file writer and all give the same, I tried as well buffered writer and add new line, still the same problem

my code for this is

```
String getTextArea_1 = textArea_1.getText();
String userHomeFolder = System.getProperty("user.home");
File file = new File(userHomeFolder, "RESULT_3.txt");
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    fw.append(getTextArea_1);
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Debug your program, and check what line-breaks ('\r\n' or only '\r') you have in the variable `getTextArea_1` and if they are compatible with your systems. Maybe you have to replace them with the proper ones.

Comment: You may also have a look into `try-with-resources`. It does the `.close()` for you. -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your try-catch to something like this:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
    String[] strings = getTextArea_1.split("\n");
    for (String s : strings){
        writer.write(s);
        writer.newLine();        
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You are awesome man.
I tried the same before, but I was declaring always the array before the try catch clauses and it never worked, thank you so much, it is a good lesson to learn ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to append a \n after your first append, or you will write on same line

Comment: What *first append*? There's only one, and that writes the whole content of the `textArea` at once.